# Ajax response issue(Access-Control-Allow-Origin.)

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my page i had a button,when clicks on that button it has an ajax call.The code follows

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#one').click(function() {

    $("#one").load(
    "http://www.ggookkll.com/pinIt/?frm_firstName=" +encodeURIComponent('frm_firstName'));
 }); });
```

But my request is recieved successfully, but iam not getting any response.

The error is

```
 Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Can anyone help me in solving this.

Comment: This might be useful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript/7605119#7605119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot* make an cross domain ajax requests.

Use proxy server to handle this. OR

Use this library to handle that
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is not completely accurate. **jQuery** can not make cross-domain AJAX requests.

Other libraries can, such as [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) and many more.